# keep file-upload value after page reload

Tags: php, html

I have a huge form that lets users (along with a lot of other inputs) upload multiple images, like this:

```
<input type="file" id="product_images" class="hidden" name="upload[]" multiple>
<input type="file" id="product_images_2" class="hidden" name="upload[]" multiple>
...
```

Now, when there is an error in a certain input (e.g. String for "description"-field too short), the page reloads. After this reload I need to keep all the posted data in all the inputs. For a text input I know how to do it, like this:

```
<input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>"/>
```

but, how can I achieve this for the `file` inputs? 
I tried something like this:

```
<input type="file" id="product_images" name="upload[]" multiple value="<?php print($_POST['upload']); ?>">
```

Did not work though. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: this will not work (if i understand you right)

Comment: You cannot due to security reasons. Google about it.

Comment: there must be a way to keep at least the selected file-path? I guess Ajax is the only solution?

Comment: save that image path in session before submit ,

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam: How do I do that? Plus, once I have saved the path, how do I put it back into the input?

Comment: see the my answer i have retrieved to input

Comment: Here is some useful link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's because you are validating in server, try to validate your field in browser, if the server reloads it will loose all your data saved in fields.

Try this validator personally i like it:
http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Hop it helps

Comment: But what if user disable javascript in his browser? Then there would be no validation at all.

Comment: maybe if that happens is better u put a warning like "If you are seeing this message is because you have disabled javascript in your browser". Or something like that. In now days no one disables javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION["image_path"] = $_POST['upload'];
<input type="file" id="product_images"<?php values= if(empty($_session['image_path'])) {} else { echo $_session['image_path']; } ?>class="hidden" name="upload[]">
```

after you retrieved ,Destroy the session

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `pattern` in your input bar that will help you , you can do it very easily

http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/10-pattern.html
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp